# Modify Android UI

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I easily modify Android UI?

For example I need to remove shutdown button or modify UIs menus in Settings according my needs?

Do I need a custon rom? I do not want to use a different UI manager (ADW, or Launcher Pro). I need to remove some UI elements.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean ?? you have an application and want to modify its UI ??? is so , how much effort it will take will depends on existing code and degree of change , else if you are talking about android OS GUI then its possible only when you have framework level code , like manufacturers of android devices have it and modify it for customized UI

Comment: I am asking about OS GUI.. Like `Settings`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the MAIN UI without having a custom rom. Removing some of the UI elements in android is deep into the frameworks, which is not possible without rebuilding the code for a particular build.

Simple answer:
**NO**

*however,* the launcher code can be changed using different launcher managers, but this is as FAR as customization is possible without rebuilding code.